# How to insert class names into the confusion matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have the following confusion matrix:

```
print (confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))

[[316 183  92  95  93  52]
[191 391  21  24  83  47]
[ 91  23 510 112  15   5]
[163  47 349 184  42  17]
[241 248  53  70  99  41]
[297 228  56  53 116 113]]
```

and I want to have the class names printed. So I write the following code:

```
confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels=['downstairs', 'jogging', 'sitting', 'standing', 'upstairs', 
'walking'])
```

and I get the error:

```
ValueError: At least one label specified must be in y_true
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Define the functions and variables involved in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`labels` parameter of `confusion_matrix` is the list of labels to index the matrix. So if you have your `y` say as `['a','b','a']` then you can use use the `labels` as `['a','b']` to index into it.

Moreover, `confusion_matrix` returns an numpy array so there is no way you can get it directly from `confusion_matrix`.

See the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) for details.

However, you can do it by coverting the numpy array into pandas dataframe

#### Sample code

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd

y_true = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2]

print (pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred), columns=['a','b','c']))
```

output:

```
   a  b  c
0  2  0  0
1  0  0  1
2  1  0  2
```

Comment: You could also set the dataframe index to abc, ie. `pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred), columns=['a','b','c'], index=['a','b','c'])`

Comment: @mac13k thank you. Can you specify a code in order to plot the confusion matrix also?

Comment: @loutsi the dataframe now represents the confusion matrix with the required columns names.

Comment: @ mujjiga yes i want to appear like this https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#:~:text=they%20could%20be%20as%20our%20choice%20for%20the%20regularization%20parameter

Comment: @loutsi I think the best way to plot the confusion matrix is to make a heatmap out of it. You can do it easily with Seaborn, see https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html